# Can I create two interchangeable classes in C# or what's the recommended way for something like this?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0

I have 2 classes that are coming from 2 projects: production and test.

`BinaryTreeNode` - is coming from a base project, and I CANNOT change.

`TreeNode` - is coming from a test project and I can change.

I would like to use these classes interchangeably in the test projects, and to convert from one to another without any issue (or at least from BinaryTreeNode to TreeNode). Could I do this in C#? If yes, how? Because if I derive it's not going to work (the objects created as BinaryTreeNode/base cannot be cast to TreeNode/derived). I cannot use cast operators because of the props that are the same type it does not work. Any idea?

```
public class BinaryTreeNode {

    public BinaryTreeNode(int key) {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Color = 0;
    }

    public int Key { get; set; }
    public BinaryTreeNode Left { get; set; }
    public BinaryTreeNode Right { get; set; }
    public BinaryTreeNode Parent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 0 = Red 
    /// 1 = Black
    /// </summary>
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// AVL Balance item
    /// </summary>
    public int Balance { get; set; }
}


public class TreeNode {
    public int val;
    public TreeNode left;
    public TreeNode right;
    public TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

Comment: Can you supply some code that shows how to convert one to another? It might be possible to write your own explicit (or implicit) conversion operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Comment: You should clarify what "I would like to use these classes interchangeably in the test projects" means. Two different classes with different set of properties are somewhat hard to "use interchangeably"

Comment: BinaryTreeNode has a loader function that return the tree (BinaryTree.LoadFromCache(...) ). I would like when the loader function returns to be able to use the result as a TreeNode - since in tests TreeNode class is the one that I am using.

Comment: There's no way to convert between the two due to _data fidelity loss_ if you were hoping for pure property conversion.  Additionally one class does not derive from the other and `TreeNode` as no concept of a hierachary (odd considering the name).  Also `TreeNode` has no `Color`; `Balance` nor `Key` properties

Comment: I am fine with losing Color property, since in the tests I don't use that one.

Comment: @user3053247 _"Color property...since in the tests I don't use that one"_ - your tests are incomplete for a `public` property

Comment: How can you have _"interchangeable classes"_ that don't share the same properties/behaviour?

Comment: I understand that issue, but do you have any solution?

Comment: Your requirements and code sample don't allow for it

Comment: Maybe look at AutoMapper

Comment: I considered AutoMapper, but I am wondering if anything else would work without getting a new dependency.

Comment: AutoMapper would not help at all if your classes don't share common properties or properties that can be converted. As I said, your design suffers from data fidelity loss

Comment: Now with accepted answer it even less clear what kind of  "interchangeable" OP was looking for...

Comment: Alexei, interchangeability and OOP in this case will not work. I accepted the problem because this is the only solution that's possible per what I see. The recursion is the trick here, since it solves the problem that I was calling out. If you have any other solution bring it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a recursive `ToTreeNode` function that copies all values to a new instance of `TreeNode`.

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TreeNode ToTreeNode(this BinaryTreeNode binary)
    {
        var treeNode = new TreeNode(binary.Key);
        treeNode.left = binary.Left?.ToTreeNode();
        treeNode.right = binary.right?.ToTreeNode();
    }
}
```

if it is important that you can just use `C# 4.0` you would have to write it like this:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TreeNode ToTreeNode(this BinaryTreeNode binary)
    {
        var treeNode = new TreeNode(binary.Key);

        if (binary.Left != null)
            treeNode.left = binary.Left.ToTreeNode();
        if (binary.Right != null)
            treeNode.right = binary.right.ToTreeNode();
    }
}
```

#### Update 1

If you really want to use casting you could implement the `explicit operator` functionality of C#. (I don´t know if the wording is correct. :D)

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public int val;
    public TreeNode left;
    public TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }

    public static explicit operator TreeNode(BinaryTreeNode b)
    {
        return b.ToTreeNode();
    }
}
```

But there are several drawbacks when taking that approach:
- It´s much cleaner to use `node.ToTreeNode()` over `(TreeNode)node`.
- Navigating through code is harder.
- You have to edit the existing `TreeNode` class. So you break the `Open-Close Principle`.

Comment: What happens to `Color`; `Key` and `Balance`?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot @JakobFerdinand!

Comment: @MickyD - I don´t know they are missing in `TreeNode`s type declaration. If they are important they have to be added to that type as well.